# change structure of url to directory-like structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know this question has been asked and answered many times, but my experience of .htaccess, regualr expressions, mod rewrites etc.. have normally drove me crazy.

I see on most websites the structure of the url is in a directory-like structure, `wwww.linku.biz/edit`. **My ultimate question is how do you do this?**

**Are all these sites behind the scenes have normal URL variables but just re-wrote?** such as `www.linku.biz/myprofile?edit="whatever"` **, is this all done with .htaccess, and mod_rewrites?**

- I want to type in my url `www.linku.biz/search` however its actually `www.linku.biz/search.php`
- I want to type in my url `www.linku.biz/JackTrow` however its actually `www.linku.biz/profile.php?us="JackTrow`
- Also I want data re-wrote when I have lots of URL data, such as `www.linku.biz/search?a=1&b=2&c=3` actually beeing `www.linku.biz/search.php?a=1&b=2&c=3`

Comment: Yes, look at the [mod-rewrite tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) or the [Apache manual on that](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). Tell what you've tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [hide .php extension - htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/hide-php-extension-htaccess)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I achieve a url like www.example.com/username to redirect to www.example.com/user/profile.php?uid=10?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9873641) or [MOD\_REWRITE HELP!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2790463) or [PHP Mod rewrite for user accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17386622)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search\.php\[?^\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?us=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Please note that your requirement 1 & 3 will both be covered by rule # 1

Answer (score 0):

Add this rules to your .htaccess file in Root folder :

To do this `www.linku.biz/JackTrow <--- www.linku.biz/profile.php?us="JackTrow`

```
 RewriteRule ^profile.php?us=(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

To do this :  `www.linku.biz/search however <--- www.linku.biz/search.php`

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Your last one , i have not understood what you want exactly.

Comment: Definitely not going to work as RewriteRule doesn't match QUERY_STRING.